# Preserve the leading zeroes of data in excel without changing the original value

Tags: node.js, excel, csv

I am trying to preserve the leading zeroes of data in excel. I came across several solutions where they're suggesting to append something to the value so that the excel treats it as a string.

For example :
`data + String.fromCharCode(8203)`

By doing this, "â€‹" this is printing in the excel, which is not what I want. Also, all such solutions are changing the original value. So I'm trying to preserve the leading zeroes in excel and at the same time keep the data from changing. So, in the process I've observed that the number (0123) in my node.js code, when I'm appending it into a CSV file, it is converting into (83). Similarly, (012) in node.js as (10) in CSV and hence excel also. Why is this happening, and to which format is it converting to? Please help me with this, thanks in advance.

Here's the node.js code :

```
const csvWriter = createCsvWriter({
    path : 'outputTaskA.csv',
    header : [
      {id : 'empID', title : 'empID'}
    ] 
});

const records = [
  {
    empID : 001234
  },
  {
    empID : 234
  },
  {
    empID : 345
  }
];

csvWriter.writeRecords(records).then(() => {
    console.log("created the file succesfully");
});
```

This is the output.csv file :

```
empID
668
234
345
```

Comment: Check csv file in notepad

Answer (score 1):

To preserve leading zeroes in Excel you can use:

```
val1,="00123",val3
```

This is Excel specific, not sure how other parsers will treat this.

Just quoting a value does not make it a string in csv (since csv has no notion of data types), quotes are there to preserve embedded separators inside fields.

Answer (score 0):

It is converting from octadecimal to decimal values. Node treats all 0-leading numbers as a prefix for octadecimal representation. i.e.:

```js
Welcome to Node.js v15.12.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> 00123
83
```

is it not possible to double quote the value of `empID` so that node treats it as string? e.g.

```js
const records = [
  {
    empID : "001234"
  },
  {
    empID : "234"
  },
  {
    empID : "345"
  }
];
```

Comment: It is possible, and node treats them as strings. But excel treats it as number and truncates the leading zeroes. And thank you for the answer :)